# Python library for accessing local wikipedia?

Tags: python, wikipedia-api

I am trying to do some research on the wikipedia data, I am good at Python.

I came across this library, seems nice: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikipedia/

I don't want to hit wikipedia directly as this is slow, and also I am trying to access a lot of data and might run into their API limits.

Can I somehow hack this to make it access a local instance of wikipedia data. I know I can run a whole wikipedia server and try to do that, but that seems a round about way.

Is there a way to just point to the folder and get this library to work as it does. Or are you aware of any other libraries that do this?

thank you.

Comment: What do you call *a local instance of wikipedia data*? A local media-wiki server ? HTML images of some wikipedia pages ? Anything other? Currently this question seems *unclear*...

Comment: My experience can be helpful for you. A script that searching on Wikipedia and organise the whole text in an article for a text to speech software: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~dragonos/dragonfire/desktop/view/head:/getcommand.py

Comment: @SergeBallesta I think wikipedia offers a compressed nightly dump for download, I was talking about this dump being kept in a folder locally. Not a full blown mediawiki server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out what I need. I think I shouldn't be searching for API, what I am looking for is a parser. Here are a couple options I have narrowed down so far. Both seem like solid starting points.

wikidump: 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wikidump/0.1.2

mwlib: 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mwlib/0.15.14

Update: While these are good parsers for wikipedia data, I found them too limiting in one way or the other, not to mention the lack of documentation. So I eventually went with good old python ElementTree and directly work with the XML.